# Look for a word of column 1 and then search that word in another column of another excel sheet and use the adjacent information to fill the cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image: this is the another excel sheet.]

[image: this is where the final information to be reflected. Also column 1 is in this sheet and the words are written in different rows.]

I am trying to organize the data into one sheet. I am looking for a way through which I will be able to extract the potential failure mode from 2nd sheet to the first sheet. The key point is that the potential failure mode should match with its respective component. So the list of components is mentioned. A way through which Potential failure modes of that respective component is detected in another excel sheet and the information which is available in the adjacent column to be extracted on the first sheet.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. It seems what you refer to second sheet is actually the 1st picture (the one with filled in PFM). So you want to match from the second picture both the product and the part number in the first picture and then put the PFM from that row into D column of the second picture?

Comment: The sheet which is filled with PFM is the 2nd sheet and the blank D column is where I want the data to reflect. Basically, the component's name is written on Process Step and function of 2nd sheet in 2nd Column. Expecting the excel would pick that up and then take the PFM information and paste it on the 1st sheet which needs to be filled.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is going to be solved with the function `=VLOOKUP`

Since you are hiding your column and sheet names, I am making some assumptions (assuming the first pic is called Sheet2 PAF is on column B and PFM is on column C). Try on Sheet1!D3 the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!B:C,2)
```

and it will fill in the FPM if a match of Sheet1!A3 is found in Sheet2!B column. You may want further reference

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1